$\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables and $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ is associated naturel filtration.
We define for each $k,n$ $S_{n,k}:= S_{n,k}(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$ a function that depend on $X_0,X_1,...,X_n$.  Assume that for each $0 \leqslant k \leqslant K$, the sequence $(S_{n,k})_{n \geqslant 0}$ is supermartingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \geqslant 0}$.
Let $\lambda > 0$. By taking the lexicographic order on $\{ (n,k) : n\geqslant 0 \text{ and } 0 \leqslant k \leqslant K \}$ (i.e $(n_1,k_1) >  (n_2,k_2)$ if and only if $n_1 > n_2$ or ( $n_1=n_2$ and $k_1> k_2$)), we define
$$
T=\inf \big\{ (n,k)\geqslant (0,0) : S_{n,k}  > \lambda \big\}.
$$
My question, let $k,n$ fixed, do we have $T \in \{ (m,k); m>n \} $ $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable ?

In general no.
$$
\begin{align*}
&\{T\in\{(m,k)\mid m>n\}\}\\
=&\left(\bigcap_{m\le n}\bigcap_{0\le\ell\le K}\{S_{m,\ell}\le\lambda\}\right)\cap\bigcup_{m\ge n+1}\left(\left(\bigcap_{0\le\ell<k-1}\{S_{m,l}\le\lambda\}\right)\cap\{S_{m,k}>\lambda\}\cap\left(\bigcap_{k+1<\ell\le K}\{S_{m,l}\le\lambda\}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Le left term $\left(\bigcap_{m\le n}\bigcap_{0\le\ell\le K}\{S_{m,\ell}\le\lambda\}\right)$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable, but not the right term. Counterexamples are easy to think of, take for instance $(X_m)_{m\ge0}$ iid standard Gaussian variables and $S_{m,\ell}=0$ for $m\le n$ and $\ell\in\{0,\cdots,K\}$. And for $m>n$ set $S_{m,k}=\lambda + X_m$ and $S_{m,\ell}=\lambda -X_m$ for $\ell\neq k$. Then
$$
\{T\in\{(m,k)\mid m>n\}\}=\{X_{n+1}>0\}\notin\mathcal F_n.
$$

Thanks very much what about if we assume that for each $0 \leqslant k \leqslant K$, the sequence $(S_{n,k})_{n \geqslant 0}$ is supermartingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}n){n \geqslant 0}$ ?

I don't see how that would help. But I could be wrong.

Thinks again. Can we say this
If we define $$
T_k:= \inf{ m\geqslant 0 \text{ such that } S_{m,k}> \lambda \text{ and for all } (m',k') < (m,k), S_{m',k'} \leqslant \lambda  }.
$$
We have the event $\big{ T_k \leqslant m \big}$ is $\mathcal{F}_m$-measurable. Since $T \in { (m,k); m>n } $ is equivalent to $T_k > n$. Since the event $\big{T_k \leqslant n\big}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, then its complementary in probability space: the event $\big{T_k > n\big}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ -measurable. Thus $T \in { (m,k); m>n } $ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.

$T_k>n$ is not equivalent to $T\in{(m,k)\mid m>n}$.

I'm super sorry for this stupid question, but why ?
$T_k>n$ is equivalent to there exists a $m>n$ such that $T_k=m$ which equivalent to there exists a $m>n$ such that $X_{m,k}> \lambda \text{ and for all } (m',k') < (m,k), X_{m',k'} \leqslant \lambda$ and the last expression is exactly the definition of $T=(m,k)$.

If $T_k>n$ then either $T_k=m$ for some $m>n$, or $T_k=+\infty$. If $T_k=m>n$ then I agree that it means $T=(m,k)$. But what if $T_k=+\infty$? You assumed $T_k$ were finite, which amounts to say that the infimum must happen on the section $\mathbb N\times{k}$. But the real issue is when $T_k=+\infty$, which means that the infimum happens in a section $\mathbb N\times{k'}$ for some $k'\neq k$.
